# ReactiveSearch onValueSelected

Tags: reactivesearch

I have the following autocomplete setup that connects to my datasource:

```
<ReactiveBase
      app="XXXXX"
      credentials="XXXXX"
    >

      <DataSearch
        componentId="title"
        :dataField="[
          'name',
          'symbol',
        ]"
        className="data-search"
        :showClear="false"
        queryFormat="and"

      />

    </ReactiveBase>
```

I would like to just alert the value of the the selection, whenever I select one of the autocomplete suggestions.

I have tried adding the following:

```
    onValueSelected = {
      function (value) {
      alert(value)
      }
    }
```

But I get a `Duplicate attribute '}'` error

I am using Vue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `onValueSelected` use `@valueSelected`. Check Event handling in Vue [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html).

You can also check this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/348k9xjyxp). I have updated the basic demo of DataSearch component present on docs to use `valueSelected`.

You can read about the other events in DataSearch component [here](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/vue/search-components/datasearch.html#events).